# Calling methods of dynamically created component angular using cmpRef

Tags: angular

I have created dynamic component on row click now i know how to access its input and output of dynamically created component, but i am wondering how to call their method using `this.cmpRef`

Answer (score 3):

You can use following snippet:

```
 (<Your_Component_Class>this.cmpRef.instance).testMethod();
```